# What are the first and the last elements in stack data structure?

Tags: data-structures, stack, element

I've studied stacks as data structures and I know that they work according to the LIFO ( Last-In-First-Out) Rule. I've encountered a problem that asks me to retrieve the first elements, as well as the last ones of the stack. Since I would rather have my knowledge double-checked by more experienced users, I am curios to know which elements of the stack are acknowledged to be the first and the last ones?

As an example, let us push in stack in this order 1,2,3,4,5,6. Which are the first two elements of the stack and which are the last two ones?

Comment: You have a tough problem there. Whoever posed the problem should have defined "first" and "last," because they're ambiguous. After all, LIFO means that the last item in is the first item out. So do they want the first in and first out, or last in and last out? When speaking of stacks, it's better to use the terms "top" and "bottom."

Answer (score 2):

It helps to think of a stack from top to bottom like a real-life stack of books. If you push book 1 on the stack, followed by books 2-6, your stack looks like:

```
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

So 1 and 2 are your first two elements (books), and 6, 5 are your last and second-to-last. Since book 6 was last, it's the first to come off the stack (**pop** in programming parlance), otherwise your stack of books will fall!

Comment: That's one interpretation. I've also known people who would say that 6 is the first item on the stack. Does "first" mean "first item to be placed on the stack," or does it mean "first item that will be popped from the stack?" In my experience, programmers' answers are pretty evenly split between the two.

Comment: I appreciate your answer!

Comment: If you go with the expansion of LIFO (and for queues, FIFO) my description lines up with the acronyms.

Answer (score 0):

On this question, people might have different opinions. What best can be done is understand the requirement of the problem in hand. Like if you are solving problems of stack on online judges then you can get the clarification from the problem statements/examples or if you are solving the problem in your professional work you can get the clarification from requirement analysis. At the end, if you could solve the problem you are supposed to, it doesn't matter you call top element as first or bottom element as first.